# How many days did it take to create the Earth in the Quran?

Tags: quran

It says the earth was created in two days.
And later on in the next verse it says four days?

Keep in mind the total duration of heavens and earth creation is six days.
So did the earth take up 2 days out of six.
or four days?

Specifically what is the meaning of the verse below about the four days.

**Verses:**

“Say (O Muhammad): Do you verily disbelieve in Him Who created the earth in **two Days**? And you set up rivals (in worship) with Him? That is the Lord of the ‘Aalameen (mankind, jinn and all that exists).

He placed therein (i.e. the earth) firm mountains from above it, and He blessed it, and measured therein its sustenance (for its dwellers) in **four Days** equal (i.e. all these four ‘days’ were equal in the length of time) for all those who ask (about its creation).

Then He rose over (Istawa) towards the heaven when it was smoke, and said to it and to the earth: ‘Come both of you willingly or unwillingly.’ They both said: ‘We come willingly.’

Then He completed and finished from their creation (as) seven heavens in **two Days** and He made in each heaven its affair. And We adorned the nearest (lowest) heaven with lamps (stars) to be an adornment as well as to guard (from the devils by using them as missiles against the devils). Such is the Decree of Him, the All-Mighty, the All-Knower”

[Fussilat 41:9-12]

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to the view that Allah created the earth itself in 2 days and did what is said in the tenth verse over a total time of 4 days

**and He made therein anchorages (i.e., mountains) from** **above it, and He blessed it, and determined therein its** **nourishments in four days [41:10].**

This means that Allah did the two things **simultaneously**. Like for example, if someone was to construct a building in 4 days and he said that he
would he would make it’s foundation in 2 days.When he says 4 days, he is including the time for making the foundation.

Comment: So is it 2 days to create earth, then 2 days to 'nourish it'? 2 days for heavens. then 2 days to create the earth. Then 2 days to set mountains etc?  Or 2 days for heavens, then 2 days to 'plan' the earth, 'determine its nourishments' then create the earth in the next 2 days. If it's the former, it's scientifically inaccurate. If the latter it's scientifically accurate.That;s the issue I'm investigating here.

Comment: Just watch this for understanding. The total is 6 days.    https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=V3KNuOj8ems

Comment: Yeah he's explaining it in a way contradictory to science. Thanks for trying though.